# Arguments passed down to C API makes no sense from child thread in Python

Tags: python, c, multithreading, ctypes

Suppose I have this code in Python:

```
def subThread():
    libc.foo(56)

def mainThread():
    libc.foo(56)

    child = threading.Thread(target=subThread)
    child.start()
```

and in C, foo would look like:

```
void foo(int a){
    printf("foo: %d\n", a);
}
```

by executing the python program, I would end up with this output

```
foo: 56
foo: 130810240
```

Have anyone encountered this situation before? Is there any solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried using thread locks? maybe there's a reentrancy limitation somewere

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thread locks as in mutex? I've tried calling .join() for the subthread, it didn't work.

Comment: yes, those locks

Answer (score 0):

How did you compile your C function to work with python? This method (https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html) requires more complex argument parsing on the C side.